# Мягкость - твердость

Tags: фонетика

В слове "цистит" звук "С" мягкий или твердый?

Answer (score 3):

Особенностью русской фонетики является **взаимное влияние зубных звуков Д/Т, З/С и  Н по твердости мягкости,** например: мост – мостик, зонт – зонтик: в сочетаниях СТ, НТ, СН и др. первый согласный произносится одинаково со вторым, то есть твердо или мягко.

***Цистит:*** сочетание согласных СТ. Звук Т мягкий, **поэтому С тоже произносится мягко.** Это не то чтобы правило, просто иначе его трудно произнести, и мы всегда имеем или твердую пару ***СТ***, или мягкую пару ***СТ***.

Правильность произношения  контролируется правилами орфоэпии, но в данном случае это **постоянное свойство,** которое в орфоэпических справочниках специально не отражается.

Мягкость согласного ***С*** иногда называют **несобственной** и, **согласно правилу**, мягкий знак после ***С*** не пишется.

Answer (score 2):

[цыс'т'ит] - мягкий, потому что произносится перед мягким  [т']

Comment: есть такое правило?

Answer (score 2):

> В слове "цистит" звук "С" мягкий или твердый?

**Мягкий.** Такое произношение фиксируется орфоэпическими словарями — к примеру, словарём Аванесова.

Что же до утверждения, что во всех словах с сочетанием СТ первый звук должен произноситься мягко, если мягко произносится второй, то с ним я не согласен. **ПРАВИЛА ТАКОГО НЕТ.** Сейчас наблюдается тенденция к отвердению первого согласного. Так, к примеру, в словах *стихнуть, стемнеть, стерпеть* и ряде других одинаково правильны в настоящее время произношения и с мягким, и с твёрдым С (см. Каленчук М.Л., Касаткин Л.Л., Касаткина Р.Ф. "Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка", М., 2012).

Наблюдается процесс отвердения первого согласного и в ряде других сочетаний согласных.